# Google Web History shows

Tags: security, google, malware

Google Web History Trends is showing URLs such as the following for 4 out of 10 of my Top Clicks (including the top 2):

- http://ocean2-4979731.org/page/0.volume
- http://ocean2-6610805.org/page/0.volume
- http://ocean2-5267347.org/page/0.volume
- http://ocean2-23139960.org/page/0.volume

I have never seen nor visited sites like this, indeed a WHOIS search shows that none of these domain names have ever been registered.

Should I check for infection by a botnet (perhaps attempting to access update URLs), or is Google just going haywire?

(Web searches for terms such as "ocean2-*.org" turn up almost no results except an unanswered question at http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web+Search/thread?tid=5797241256dbfcee)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a bit of poking around, this is the best explanation I found:

> If you use a google books search and
>   click the star next to the book found
>   in google web history the notebook
>   loads something akin to the follow:
>
> *God and Reason in the Middle Ages   ocean2-125956.org/page/0.volume*
>
> **Presumably the URL is of some internal form and produces a Server
>   not Found error.**  As I am trying to
>   create a  set of bookmarks for
>   students to access material published
>   via google books,  this is a...

From http://markmail.org/message/ckxshtvbqs2yoonm

**Edit:  Here are a couple more links to backup the previous theory.

Basically, you have a Google Books result (H. H. Richardson: Complete Architectural Works), with the (possibly internal) URL (http://ocean2-7300440.org/page/0.volume)

[Link 1](http://tinyurl.com/kjuudc)
[Link 2](http://tinyurl.com/mmtwlu)

Anapologetos

Comment: FYI, SF is messing up the final two links...

Comment: Fixed the borked links, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I wonder why there are so few mentions of this online. Thanks for taking the time to reply :)